# What is the actual node's CPU and memory capacity here?

Tags: kubernetes

I would like to know, what are the actual memory and CPU capacity in mi and m in the following results:

```
Capacity:
 alpha.kubernetes.io/nvidia-gpu:    0
 cpu:                   2
 memory:                2050168Ki
 pods:                  20
Allocatable:
 alpha.kubernetes.io/nvidia-gpu:    0
 cpu:                   2
 memory:                2050168Ki
 pods:                  20
```

Comment: Do you think `kubectl get nodes` is returning something substantially different from the hardware capabilities?  Or are these numbers coming from somewhere else?

Comment: I actually run a minikube and then execute "kubectl describe node" command and got those results.

Comment: cpu `2` is equals to `2000m`, and your memory in Ki (kibibytes) just divide by 1024 to get the value in Mi (mebibytes: `2002Mi`)... Check more about on the docs https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-compute-resources-container/

Answer (score 1):

2 CPUs (2 cores) and 2050168Kb of RAM (more simply, 2GB). Which also happens to be the Minikube defaults.